# CSS - unable to disable margin for DIV generated by FlipClock.JS

Tags: html, css, margin, flipclock

Really weird one.
I have a Div element that contains a counter using FlipClock.js
There is some kind of margin to the right of it which I cannot override in CSS.
 No matter how I treat the element (inline style in tools or the CSS itself, I cannot get rid of it and it's pushing other content).
You'll need F12 and select the Div that has class "fclock flip-clock-wrapper".
 You'll notice the highlight on it shows you that it takes extra space as if it was assigned a margin.
Here's a fiddle in which the Plugin and Original CSS are located:
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/guoneajk/)
HTML:

```
    <td>
      <div class="fclock"></div>
    </td>
```

CSS override:

```
    .fclock {
transform-origin: 0 0;
transform: scale(.30);
-ms-transform: scale(.30);
-webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
-webkit-transform: scale(.30);
-o-transform-origin: 0 0;
-o-transform: scale(.30);
-moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
-moz-transform: scale(.30);
}
```

JS:

```
     var currentDate = new Date(); 
// Set some date in the future. ***change to desired date***

var futureDate = new Date(2016, 07, 30, 08, 0, 0); //fixed as per comments
// Calculate the difference in seconds between the future and current date 
var diff = futureDate.getTime() / 1000 - currentDate.getTime() / 1000; 

var clock = $('.fclock').FlipClock(diff, {
   clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
   countdown: true
});
```

Comment: CSS has a thing called "specificity". You should read more about that on W3Schools or MDN. I assume your selector is not as specific as the library's. Or the library has overridden yours because it was declared later or was using `!important`.

Comment: Have you looked into the Fiddle? Try to play with it and see what you think after. I have.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't see that at first because I assumed you tried `margin:0`? I don't see that your code in hope of trying to disable the margin.

Comment: I did about everything I know to remove it and I do not know what generates it. I played with everything. My override CSS doesn't include the margin setting because I wanted to leave everything exactly like it is before any messing around with the margin.

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm getting what you mean now. You are talking about the number that got pushed to the second row.

Comment: I wasn't able to disable it and restored the CSS to what it has been before I started messing with it, so that the person looking at it will have the same starting point as I had before I tryed to fix it. Can you have a go at it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118740/discussion-between-adi-solar-and-daniel-cheung).

Answer (score 0):

Override the style definition for `.flip-clock-wrapper ul` in the flipclock.css as shown below:

**Code:**

```
.flip-clock-wrapper ul.flip {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    width: auto;
    height: 80px;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: inherit;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background: #000;
    padding: 24px;
}
```

[**Fiddle or it didn't happen**](http://jsfiddle.net/guoneajk/2/)

PS: Notice how I've updated the CSS Selector from `.flip-clock-wrapper ul`  to `.flip-clock-wrapper ul.list` to make use the CSS specificity behavior to ensure my style declaration overrides the one from the CSS file.

Comment: I don't get it, cause there's still a gap after the clock. If you F12 it you can see it's marked by highlight when selecting it. I'm in your Fiddle... If I give a fixed width of 620px to the wrapper, the numbers allign but there is still a gap and it pushed the rest of my content on the page (which is not in the FIddle).

Comment: That gap is because the  `:before` and `:after` selectors for the `.fclock.flip-clock-wrapper` div have `display: table` style applied to them. Just change it to `display:none` and that extra space will disappear.